# JAVA 2D String array column numbers

Tags: java, csv, multidimensional-array, split

I have a CSV file which I have to read to a 2D string array (it must be a 2D array)

However it has different column number, like:

> One, two, three, four, five
>
> 1,2,3,4

So I want to read those into an array. I split it everything is good, however I don't know how not to fill the missing columns with NULLs.

The previous example is:

> 0: one,two,three,four,five (length 5)
>
> 1: 1,2,3,4,null (length 5)

However I want the next row's length to be 4 and not 5 without null.

Is this possible?

This is where I've got so far (I know it's bad):

```
public static void read(Scanner sc) {
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        temp.add(sc.nextLine().replace(" ", ""));
    }
    String[] row = temp.get(0).split(",");
    data = new String[temp.size()][row.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.size(); ++i) {
        String[] t = temp.get(i).split(",");
        for (int j = 0; j < t.length; ++j) {
            data[i][j] = t[j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: show your code please

Comment: Added it to the post sorry

Comment: Can you know will be the length of the array? I mean after read the csv, can you determine which must be the length for the array? I'm asking this because once initialized the object, you can´t resize it.

Comment: you could use a List<String> for example to add just the elements which contains a value and are not empty.

Comment: Well I can't really determine it, and that is the problem.
There is a test for this:
data[0] = one,two,three,four,five -> length MUST be 5
data[1] = 1,2,3,4 -> length MUST be 4
and in the same 2D array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a non-rectangular 2-dimensional array.  You'll want to avoid defining the second dimension on your 2D array.  Here's an example:

```
final Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src/main/resources/csvfile");
final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);

final String[][] arrays = new String[lines.size()][];
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
    arrays[i] = lines.get(i).split(",");
}
```

All lines are read into a List so that we know the first dimension of the 2D array.  The second dimension for each row is determined by the result of the split operation.

Comment: bingo! Thanks a lot for your answer.